# Switching to landscape view and using a tab bar controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, view

I am using a tab bar controller for my app. If I'm in one of the view controllers called "results" and  the ios device rotates to landscape mode, it switches for another view I created called landScape. This has been done within the method

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrient‌​ation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        self.view=landScape;
    } else {
        self.view=originalView;
    }
}
```

It works just fine whenever I am in that specific controller within the tab bar (example results view controller). However; If I go to another element in my tab bar controller and my phone is tilted in landscape mode and then I decide to go to resultsviewcontroller, it does not call upon my view landScape, instead it tries to autosize the view on its own and it looks awful. Should I call the method -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration   within my viewDidLoad method to solve the problem? Or is this completely wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're only setting `resultsViewController.view` when it is the active view controller and detects a rotation.  Try this:

```
- (void)setViewForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    self.view = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)
        ? originalView
        : landScape;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    [self setViewForInterfaceOrientation:[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    [super viewWillAppear];
}

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrient‌​ation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self setViewForInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rob. This is how I was doing it, what do you think?

Comment: -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration                                                    {
    
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation 
                                   duration:duration];
    
    
     if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
     {
         self.view=landScape;
     
     
     }


else
{
   self.view=originalView;
    


}

Comment: put it in yours... sorry I am new to this

Comment: @marcus13 you can add your own answer, even to your own question (if it makes sense)

Comment: I've changed my answer based on your current implementation.

Comment: Thanks rob, about to give it a try. From a quick glance, what did you want me to do with "original view"? Back in viewDidLoad, I had this set as:    self.originalView=self.view;

Comment: You probably still need to do that so you can use it in setViewForInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: with that being said rob, I am getting a warning for the line...   [self setViewForInterfaceOrientation:[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]];      the warning is:  warning: Semantic Issue: Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UIDeviceOrientation' to different enumeration type 'UIInterfaceOrientation'

Comment: You could try using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation` instead.